# phone according to the format number

Tags: html

i would like to ask how to make my phone according to this format : 
   +6012-1234 567
   below are the code that i have done ...when i run it it say press match the request format ... so what wrong with my code ??

```
<div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableCell"><label for="Phone">Phone :</label>
  </div>
 <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp; 
<input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}
[\-]\d{4}" tittle="Malaysia phone format only" placeholder="+6015-123-4567"  
 phone="phone"> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: pattern="\+\d{4}[\-]\d{3}
[\-]\d{4}

Comment: @Ammar it doest not work :( it still pop out the message

Comment: You have an example with a plus sign and then four initial digits 6012 followed by a second set of four, and then a pattern with no plus sign and three initial digits `\d{3}` followed by another set of three. Which is it?

Comment: Even though not mentioned that you might want it, I would suggest using a plugin that masks your phone number e.g. [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" /> or <input type="tel" /> you have added type="phone"
HTML5 Input Types
color
date 
datetime-local
email
month
number
range
search
tel
time
url
week
```

Comment: You have added input type="phone" but "phone" is not types of html5. you can use number instead of phone